# HTML form's hidden input value changes on server side

Tags: html, django, post, hidden-field

I'm getting this strange behavior with html post form. I'm trying to send a hidden variable on post.

```
<input type="hidden" name="skip" id="skip" value="true"/>
```

While writing server side scripts, I was expecting to fetch a value from post to be "true". But what I actually receive is "Skip".

```
> print request.POST["skip"]
> "Skip"
```

Whats going wrong? I'm using django framework, is django causing this problem?

Comment: Do you have another input with the same name?

Comment: No, atleast not in the same form.

Comment: Are you sure? Is the submit button not perhaps named "Skip" as well? Post the HTML of the whole form.

Comment: Somebody has associated a post event with the same submit button, which sent the value "Skip". I'm not sure how the priority between different posts works, but removing that post call solved the problem. I'll close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler from http://www.fiddler2.com/ to see what is actually being submitted

Answer (score 0):

use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see the POST that is send to the server